# How to validate multiple items in shopping cart

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress, shopping-cart

I a learning cypress and new to javascript I need your help. I want to validate, weather the items, I added to cart, are in my bag, and as I iterate through my bag, it only validates first item, instead my whole collection and it gives this assertion error:

> Expected `<p.product-name>` to have text 'Cauliflower - 1 Kg Cashews - 1 Kg', but the text was 'Cauliflower - 1 Kg'

Should I use implicit assertion or explicit one

My code:

```js
/// <reference types="Cypress" />
    describe('Example_Test_Suite_1',()=>{

        it("Products are added to cart",()=>{
            cy.visit("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/seleniumPractise/#/")
            cy.get('.products').as('productlocator')
            cy.wait(2000)
        cy.get('@productlocator').find('.product').each(($el, index, $list) => {

            const textVeg = $el.find('h4.product-name').text()
            if (textVeg.includes('Cashews')||textVeg.includes('Cauliflower')) {
                cy.wrap($el).find('button').click()
            }
            })
            cy.get('.cart-icon').click()
            // cy.get('li\[class*="cart-item"\] p\[class="product-name"\]:visible')
            // .should('have.text','Cauliflower - 1 Kg')
            
            cy.get('li\[class*="cart-item"\]').find(' p\[class="product-name"\]:visible').should('have.length',2).each(($el, index, $list) => {
                cy.wrap($el).should('have.text','Cauliflower - 1 Kg','Cashews - 1 Kg') // code for bag validation
                
               
                
               
         })

            
    })
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use `.should()` and `.and()` to assert two items in the cart.

```js
cy.get('.cart-icon').click();

cy.get('li.cart-item')
  .should('contain', 'Cashews - 1 Kg')
  .and('contain', 'Cauliflower - 1 Kg');
```

Answer (score 1):

The test can be simple, you don't need `.each()` for locating a vege just select the `.product` with the name.

On the cart checkout list, use `.eq(0)` for first and `.eq(1)` for second item.

The `cy.wait(2000)` is not needed, the first search you do already has 4000 second timeout which will cover the wait period, or if you have slow network increase the timeout on first search.

Use `cy.contains()` and `.should('contain', ...)` for text search so that any whitespace around the text does not cause you problems.

```js
cy.visit('https://rahulshettyacademy.com/seleniumPractise');

// Add two products
cy.contains('.product', 'Cashews', {timeout: 6000})   
  .find('button')
  .click()

cy.contains('.product', 'Cauliflower')
  .find('button')
  .click()

// Check the cart
cy.get('.cart-icon').click()

cy.get('li.cart-item').eq(0)
  .should('contain', 'Cashews - 1 Kg')

cy.get('li.cart-item').eq(1)
  .should('contain', 'Cauliflower - 1 Kg')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways:

1. Using an Array

```js
const vegetables = ['Cauliflower - 1 Kg', 'Cashews - 1 Kg']

cy.get('li[class*="cart-item"]')
  .find(' p[class="product-name"]:visible')
  .should('have.length', 2)
  .each(($el, index, $list) => {
    cy.wrap($el).should('have.text', vegetables[index])
  })
```

2. Using the `to.be.oneOf` assertion

```js
cy.get('li[class*="cart-item"]')
  .find(' p[class="product-name"]:visible')
  .should('have.length', 2)
  .each(($el, index, $list) => {
    expect($el.text()).to.be.oneOf(['Cauliflower - 1 Kg', 'Cashews - 1 Kg'])
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cy.contains()` for validating each of your item in the cart if the order of them does not matter.

```js
cy.contains('.cart-item', 'Cashews - 1 Kg').should('be.visible')
cy.contains('.cart-item', 'Cauliflower - 1 Kg').should('be.visible')
```

You may even use `.within()` to limit your scope to the cart element only instead of the entire page.

```js
cy.get('.cart-items')
  .should('be.visible')
  .within(() => {
    cy.contains('.cart-item', 'Cashews - 1 Kg').should('be.visible')
    cy.contains('.cart-item', 'Cauliflower - 1 Kg').should('be.visible')
  })
```